# Verification of homomorphically encrypted computations

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is there a way to prove the accuracy of computations performed on homomorphically encrypted cypher text?

Comment: Without specifying which cryptosystem was used, this question can't be answered. And even then, I don't think that's possible without leaking information.

Comment: Accuracy or correctness? What is the exact scenario you are looking at? For example, I send my encrypted inputs to the cloud, the cloud computes some known function on those inputs and sends me the result with a proof that it computed the correct function in the correct manner.

Comment: What does that proof look like? Are there any papers that look at this proof?

Comment: I'm not sure if the results in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/202.pdf) still hold, but verifiable computation on encrypted data is probably what you are looking for. Though I can't be sure since you never answered my questions.